# Trying to while-loop my way through a binary file until a certain byte but the loop never ends

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, while-loop, binaryfiles, blender

I've been working on an import script and have managed to hammer out most of the issues up until this point-I need to loop through the vertices until I reach a byte header that proceeds them but despite trying re.match, re.search, and !=
the while loop simply continues till the end of the file. I'm not sure where I went wrong given regex works with the if statement prior to this section of code.

```
while re.match(b'\x05\xC0.x\6E', byte) is None:

            #Fill the vertex list by converting byte to its little endian float value
            vertex[0] = struct.unpack('<f', byte)
            byte = f.read(4)
            vertex[1] = struct.unpack('<f', byte)
            byte = f.read(4)
            vertex[2] = struct.unpack('<f', byte)

            #Append the vertices list with the completed vertex
            vertices.append(vertex)
            vertex_count += 1

            #Read in what will either be the next X coordinate or a file header
            byte = f.read(4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is reading 4 bytes each time, but the pattern is 6 bytes-long.

```
>>> len(b'\x05\xC0.x\6E')
6
>>> b'\x05\xC0.x\6E' == b'\x05' + b'\xC0' + b'.' + b'x' + b'\6' + b'E'
True
```

The pattern will never match. That's why it continue until the end of the file.

IMHO, you mean this: (swapping the last `\`  and `x`)

```
b'\x05\xC0.\x6E'
```

---

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(b'\x05\xC0.x\6E', b'\x05\xC0\x00\x6E')  # no match
>>> re.match(b'\x05\xC0.\x6E', b'\x05\xC0\x00\x6E')  # match
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match=b'\x05\xc0\x00n'>
```

Comment: I thought "." was a wildcard, it was supposed to be looking for variations of the 8-bit header.

Comment: @GregSolidus, You're right: `.` is a wildcard character in regular expression. What you missed is: expressing `\x6E` as `x\6E`

Comment: Whoops. That fixed it.